# How to update Numpy on Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, numpy

How can I update Numpy into the newest one? Should I download .dmg file from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/

Is this .dmg only for 10.5? I have installed numpy using these instructions:

http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X

My current Numpy is 1.2.1. I'm running on Mac OS X 10.6.1 Snow Leopard. Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`sudo easy_install -U numpy`

Installing via setuptools will get the new numpy on the sys.path for non-system utilties (I've been told that some Apple utilities rely on the system-numpy). In general, setuptools will "do the right" thing on OS X.

Comment: As noted by Austin, you have to install http://r.research.att.com/gfortran-4.2.3.dmg first. Tested on a new 10.6.4 install

Comment: I had similar problems trying

    sudo easy_install -U numpy

So I did the following:

    sudo easy_install pip

to install pip. Than installed numpy via `pip` 

     pip install numpy

which worked great.

Answer (score 6):

Use `pip install -U numpy` instead, as easy_install is deprecated in favor of `pip`

Answer (score 4):

as suggested elsewhere, macports works fine on multiple architecture and versions of MacOsX + allows updates and more:

```
$ port search numpy
py-numpy @1.3.0 (python)
    The core utilities for the scientific library scipy for Python

py25-numpy @1.3.0 (python)
    The core utilities for the scientific library scipy for Python

py25-symeig @1.4 (python, science)
    Symeig - Symmetrical eigenvalue routines for NumPy.

py26-numpy @1.3.0 (python)
    The core utilities for the scientific library scipy for Python

py26-scikits-audiolab @0.10.2 (python, science, audio)
    Audiolab is a python toolbox to read/write audio files from numpy arrays

Found 5 ports.
$
```

in your case, simply issue :

```
$ sudo port install py26-numpy
```

alternatively, if you want / need to compile yourself, the instructions in [HJBlog](http://blog.hyperjeff.net/?p=160) are very useful. I tested and could easily compile the 64-bit version of matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, easy_install -U numpy didn't work.

```
print numpy.__version__
```

would always give 1.2.1

So, I first removed numpy 1.2.1 by finding it and deleting the entire folder:

```
import numpy
print numpy.__file__
```

I downloaded the GNU Fortran Compiler from:

http://r.research.att.com/gfortran-4.2.3.dmg

I used easy_install to install numpy.

In retrospect, easy_install -U numpy might have worked if I had the Fortran compiler installed.